# Why is infix not properly extracting the correct columns from my fixed-width text file?

Tags: stata

I have a fixed-width text file named "OASH2010.txt" that looks like the following

```
201081127501F   H   22  99920   0   0   13860921    0   1.0000
201081127501F   H   23  99930   0   0   410026345   0   1.0000
201081129301F   H   1   71131   27  51602   1268275327  24578.03    1.0000
201081129301F   H   12  99901   0   0   1268275327  0   1.0000
201081129301F   H   13  99203   0   0   415264  0   1.0000
201081129301F   H   16  99905   28  5798406 14206094    2.45    1.0000
201081129301F   H   17  99906   0   0   23261260    0   1.0000
201081129301F   H   18  99907   27  4210    27357876    6498.31 1.0000
201081129301F   H   20  99204   0   0   12470   0   1.0000
201081129301F   H   21  99220   0   0   4044298 0   1.0000
```

The columns in the file can be extracted based on the character location provided in a README file. For example, the year variable is in the first 4 characters, the observation ID is in the 5th to 12th characters, and so on and so forth.

In order to extract the columns from the text file, I run the following code

```
#delimit ;
clear;
infix
str YEAR    1-4
str FACT_ID 5-12
str BLK     13-13
str H_I1    14-15
str H_I3    16-20
str H_I4    21-23
str H_I5    24-39
str H_I6    40-54
str H_I7    55-69
str MULT    70-78
using "OASH2010.txt";
```

From my understanding, infix should ignore the spaces and search until it encounters the next character. This code was not mine originally so presumably the person who wrote it was able to extract the columns from the data. However, it doesn't properly identify and extract the correct columns. I get the following in Stata

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening? Suggestions for how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, `infix` should ignore the spaces and search
>   until it encounters the next character.

Not my understanding: `infix` should respect the instructions on columns that you give it; that's the point! Else you need another command to do what you want.

I can't speak to the presumption that this worked for someone else. The evidence is that the command you give don't match the file you show.

What seems evident is the first three variables are contiguous in the data file. Thereafter, the convention switches to space separation. It's a mess.

In a situation like this, I don't agonise about how to input. I read everything in as one string variable and then write custom code.

```
clear 
infix str DATA 1-80 using OASH2010.txt 
gen YEAR = real(substr(DATA, 1, 4))  
gen FACT_ID = substr(DATA, 5, 8) 
gen BLK = substr(DATA, 13, 1) 
replace DATA = substr(DATA, 14, .) 
split DATA, gen(H_I) destring 
rename HI_8 MULT
```

It seems obvious that `YEAR` can be made numeric. Conversely, some of the other variables seem identifiers of some kind and if so are better left as string. Using `destring` as an option on `split` is literally optional; a selective `destring` on what you know should really be numeric is good strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. My confusion comes from the fact that I have to do this for many files and for some (more than 2/3) of the files it works.  In the files where it works, they are formatted in a similar way, namely there are spaces between some of the columns and not in others. The corresponding infix command for these files, however, doesn't account for these spaces and yet was still able to correctly infer the columns.